# Android keyboard loses focus on touch in Page Renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an app with a custom keyboard. To do this, I use a page renderer so I can use an Android layout which makes the keyboard logic a lot easier to handle.

When I do a longish press (.5s) on the keyboard, everything works great. When I do a quick tap on a key (what most people do), the `EditText` targeted by the keyboard loses focus, causing the keyboard to hide and the cursor to be removed from the `EditText`. I set up a `FocusChanged` handler to hide the keyboard when the user clicks elsewhere on the screen. With this error, when I do `FindFocus` after a keyboard tap, the focus returns as `null`. I showed layout bounds in case of some ghost view receiving the click, but there's nothing there. I don't know what the lifecycle is on a keyboard event, but whatever is causing this issue is called after `mKeyboardView.Key`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
class KeyboardPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{

    public CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    public EditText mTargetView;
    public Android.InputMethodServices.Keyboard mKeyboard;
    Activity activity;
    global::Android.Views.View view;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            SetupUserInterface();
            SetupEventHandlers();
            this.AddView(view);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"           ERROR: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void SetupUserInterface()
    {
        activity = this.Context as Activity;
        view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, this, false);

        mKeyboard = new Android.InputMethodServices.Keyboard(Context, Resource.Xml.keyboard);
        mTargetView = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.target);

        mKeyboardView = view.FindViewById<CustomKeyboardView>(Resource.Id.keyboard_view);
        mKeyboardView.Keyboard = mKeyboard;
    }

    void SetupEventHandlers()
    {
        mTargetView.Touch += (sender, e) =>
        {
            ShowKeyboardWithAnimation();
            e.Handled = false;
            mTargetView.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        };

        mTargetView.FocusChange += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var idk = FindFocus();
            if (!mTargetView.IsFocused)
            {
                mKeyboardView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }

        };

        mKeyboardView.Key += (sender, e) =>
        {
            long eventTime = JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
            KeyEvent ev = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEventActions.Down, e.PrimaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEventFlags.SoftKeyboard | KeyEventFlags.KeepTouchMode);

            DispatchKeyEvent(ev);
        };
    }


    public void ShowKeyboardWithAnimation()
    {
        if (mKeyboardView.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone)
        {
            mKeyboardView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            Android.Views.Animations.Animation animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(
                Context,
                Resource.Animation.slide_up_bottom
            );
            mKeyboardView.ShowWithAnimation(animation);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout (bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout (changed, l, t, r, b);

        var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec (r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
        var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec (b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

        view.Measure (msw, msh);
        view.Layout (0, 0, r - l, b - t);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/Nasby/CustomKeyboard). iOS project is working pretty well if anyone is looking to implement that as well.

Comment: Your `mTargetView.FocusChange` delegate is the reason.

Comment: I tried commenting it out and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, cant reproduce your problem, would you mind share a basic demo to reproduce this problem ?

Comment: Did you try it in a page renderer or just inside an Android page? Everything worked fine before I tried to get it working in a renderer. I'll upload the project to Github in a bit so you can try running it yourself. Thanks.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Hey, I edited my question to include a repo to the project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `EditText.FocusChange` method and modify your  `CustomKeyboardView.Key` method like this :

```
mKeyboardView.Key += (sender, e) =>
{
    long eventTime = JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
    KeyEvent ev = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEventActions.Down, e.PrimaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEventFlags.SoftKeyboard | KeyEventFlags.KeepTouchMode);

    //Make your editText get Focus
    mTargetView.RequestFocus();

    DispatchKeyEvent(ev);
};
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIGh2.gif).

---

## Update :

Here is my workaround :

```
mKeyboardView.Key += async (sender, e) =>
{
    long eventTime = JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
    KeyEvent ev = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEventActions.Down, e.PrimaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEventFlags.SoftKeyboard | KeyEventFlags.KeepTouchMode);

    DispatchKeyEvent(ev);
    await Task.Delay(1);

    //mTargetView.RequestFocus();
 };
```

Then, the cursor will always be visible.

[Effect like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT9w9.gif).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Dismissing the keyboard by clicking away from the keyboard no longer works after removing the `FocusChange` code. The typing definitely works better now, but notice the cursor disappears every other letter which is not good.
Edit:
I added a `RemoveKeyboard` view to the layout that takes up the entire area not used by the `Keyboard` or `EditText`. I hide the `Keyboard` on touching this view, fixing the keyboard hiding issue, however there is still is a cursor issue.

Comment: @WillNasby, I have update my answer, please check it.