# Can't write text on forced keyboard Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-edittext, keyboard

I'm doing my own custom rich text editor in Android using Xamarin, with possibilities of adding/removing bold, underline, italic, color (etc) attributes on the selection. I was losing focus every time I  clicked on a button that set one of these attributes so I found the solution with the soft keyboard. 
But with the soft keyboard that opens

> **I can't write more text**

even though I have forced the focus on the `EditText`. The keys pressed do nothing.
Here's the code I'm using to force the soft keyboard to show :

```
_myEditText.FocusChange += _MyEditText_OnFocusChanged;
```

and

```
private void _editor_FocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs e)
{
    _myEditText.RequestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
    imm.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Implicit, 0);

}
```

Is there a way to keep the keyboard open and being able to write new text in the `EditText`? I've tried with the `ShowSoftInput()` and the `ShowFlags.Forced` tag and even the `ShowSoftInputOnFocus` property on `_myEditText` but results are the same.

**EDIT**

I made a sample in Native Android with Android Studio and the keyboard works perfectly OK even without the use of the `InputMethodManager` ... what am I missing. Is there something in Xamarin that's not working properly ? Because in native it has the exact behaviour that I'm unable to make in xamarin.

**EDIT 2**

It seems related to the fact I'm using the AppCompat.ViewRenderer of Xamarin.Android and not the basic ViewRenderer. On my way to test it.

**EDIT 3**

After a long time testing every environment and possibilities, I've come to a conclusion that the code IS working the same way as in a native application but with a custom renderer,

> **ONLY** if my clicks on the buttons are **at least** ~0.5s long.

If a do an instant click, I lose the focus of my EditText, but if I stay pressed on the button a little longer, the button action is fired, the keyboard stays open and the selection is impacted by the style changement.

Here is some basic code to reproduce the problem as easy as possible.
Just create a basic forms app. And then add the 3 following class

My forms custom view : (empty)

```
 public class RichTextEditor : View
 {

 }
```

My android renderer :

```
using Android.App;
using TestFocusApplicationForms.CustomViews;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RichTextEditor), typeof(TestFocusApplicationForms.Droid.RichTextEditorRenderer_Droid))]
namespace TestFocusApplicationForms.Droid
{
    public class RichTextEditorRenderer_Droid : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer<RichTextEditor, Android.Views.View>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<RichTextEditor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (Control == null)
            {
                Activity activity = this.Context as Activity;
                var view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TestFocus_Layout, this, false);
                SetNativeControl(view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `TestFocus_Layout.axml` file corresponding :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end">
      <Button
          android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="B"
            android:id="@+id/boldButton" />
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="I"
            android:id="@+id/italicButton" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Texte riche"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:imeOptions="actionNone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How did you set the attribute in your `EditText` ? Please share more code to reproduce this problem.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I used the SetSpan(style, startIndex, endIndex, SpanTypes) method on the selection of the editText. And this works just fine, this isn't the problem. The problem is that the newly opened keyboard doesn't work

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I found that it seems to be related to the fact that i'm using Custom Renderer displaying this rich text editor, because it seems to be working on both Native Android platform and Xamarin.Android without Xamarin Forms and custom renderers. Forgot to mention i'm using Xamarin.forms and rendering this view in a Page with a CustomRenderer.

Comment: I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem, and you could refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290316/android-keyboard-loses-focus-on-touch-in-page-renderer), it's a little similar to your problem.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Thank you for your answer. I've updated my post with some basic code to reproduce the bug I have and your link helped figured out I also had the "delay" thing on my buttons. If I do a not-instantaneous press it works, otherwise the keyboard is closed and focus is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, it might not be the best in term of long term design but it works.
I made my own `VisualElementRenderer` for my `RichTextEditor` Class, and removed all unnecessary code and more important, removed code overriding the default focus behaviour of the element. 
Also, it seems the fact that inflating the layout from a .axml file would cause different behaviour as creating the views programmatically, so I made a RichTextEditor_Droid class containing simple conversion of my .axml in C#. And I removed the `FocusChange` eventHandler on my `EditText`.
Here is my renderer :

```
public class RichTextEditorRenderer_Droid :
        Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer<RichTextEditor>
    {
        public Android.Views.View NativeView { get; private set; }

        public RichTextEditorRenderer_Droid(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        public RichTextEditorRenderer_Droid()
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(
            ElementChangedEventArgs<RichTextEditor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (NativeView == null)
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);

                var activity = Context as Activity;
                var textPad = new RichTextEditor_Droid(this.Context);

                var textPadLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                activity.SetContentView(textPad, textPadLayoutParams);

                NativeView = textPad;
            }
        }

        bool _disposed;
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && !_disposed)
            {
                if (NativeView != null && ManageNativeControlLifetime)
                {
                    RemoveView(NativeView);
                    NativeView.Dispose();
                    NativeView = null;
                }

                _disposed = true;
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Now I've got another problem cause I have no more AppBar when this view is rendered on Android. But that is out of context. So thank you @YorkShen-MSFT for helping.